# Identify NIC on which HTTP response come

Tags: c#, .net, http, network-programming

I have multiple NIC on my desktop.  I am communication to one server using HTTP. When I send and receive response.  I want to know out of all which NIC is getting used for communicating for a particular HTTP request.

I need to know this as multiple some of NIC can be connected to  private network and only one NIC is connected to desired HTTP server for which I want to host Callback URL.  I am using C#, .Net 4.0

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds to me like a very brittle application in the making.

Comment: @Andrew I think there are legitimate reasons for wanting to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really ask from which NIC the request comes from, because you shouldn't care. But you can get the IP on which the request came in:

```
var localAddress = Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
```

You can find more about server variables [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As Dave Van den Eynde says plus this gets the IP addresses of the adapters on the machine:-

```
  foreach (NetworkInterface netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + netInterface.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Description: " + netInterface.Description);
    Console.WriteLine("Addresses: ");
    IPInterfaceProperties ipProps = netInterface.GetIPProperties();
    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation addr in ipProps.UnicastAddresses)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(" " + addr.Address.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks...This will list all the NIC on my desktop. I would like to get the NIC using which I am able to communicate with HTTP server.  Sometime it can be a Wifi adapter or user can be accessing using VPN also

Comment: Get the incoming IP address as Dave Van den Eynde says then iterate through the list looking for that IP address.

Answer (score 1):

.NET's HTTPWebRequest and related objects do not plumb the LocalEndpoint information up the stack for you. If you use something like FiddlerCore, you could try the request on each interface, or you could use a technique like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/03/09/mapping-socket-or-port-to-owner-process-in-c-sharp-dotnet.aspx to attempt to infer which local adapter was used for an in-progress connection.

But generally, this approach is going to be fragile, and you should consider carefully whether you really need this feature.

Comment: Thanks @EricLaw -MSFT As i mentioned

Comment: Thanks @EricLaw -MSFT  Is there any other alternative to figure out which adapter is best suitaed to host the Callback URL so it can recive the events from a particular HTTP server which will send error in response to a requset. I use GETBestInterface() but its not giving the best match when user is logged in using VPN, it is returning number in the range 64xxx